# Issue binding click events for radio form elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have follow html code:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
   <label><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="1" id="RadioGroup1_0" />Radio1</label>
    <br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="2" id="RadioGroup1_1" />Radio2</label>
    <br>
    <label for="text">Text inlocuit</label><input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
</form>
```

and a jquery simple function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#RadioGroup1_0").click(function() {
        $("input#text").empty();
        $("input#text").val()=1;       
    });

    $("#RadioGroup1_1").click(function() {
        $("input#text").empty();
        $("input#text").val()=2;       
    });

});
</script>
```

And is not working.It's obviously that I made something wrong.
I try with simple radio and binding 'click', 'change', 'mousedown'.
jQuery version 1.7.1

Comment: "i[t']s not working" is neither an analysis of the problem nor any indication of debugging/research.

Comment: Why -5? Give the guy a break, we've all been there.

Comment: Not the problem, but if you're selecting by id then select by _just_ id. I.e., `$("#text")` _not_ `$("input#text")`.

Comment: Ofcourse I did analysis before posting here, but it's incomprehensible for me, why if is into a form it doesn't work. Sorry my language, I'm not an English speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
        $("#text").val($(this).index("input[type='radio']")+1);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C7sbs/

---

you can use

```
$("#text").val(this.value);
```

or

```
$("#text").val($(this).index("input[type='radio']")+1);
```

Comment: +1 for a good guess on what the OP actually wants.

Comment: try this working sample http://jsfiddle.net/C7sbs/

Comment: why not just `$("#text").val( this.value );`

Answer (score 2):

The new value goes inside the parenthesis:

```
 $("input#text").val(2);
```

`empty` removes children, it doesn't clear out the value; there is no reason to call it on a text input.

Answer (score 0):

this is the way to assign value: `$("input#text").val("2");`

Comment: No need for quotes on a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#RadioGroup1_0").click(function() {
        $("input#text").val("1");
    });

    $("#RadioGroup1_1").click(function() {
        $("input#text").val("2");
    });

});
</script>
```

this definitely works - check the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/B3dUc/8/

have you included a reference to jquery?

Comment: do you have a reference to jquery?

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$(document).ready( function(){

 $("input[type='radio']").click( function(){
     var val = $(this).val();
     $('#text').val(val);
    });
});
```